# MSBuild works in Debug Configuration but fails in release in azure devops

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

i am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline in azure devops for my project now this project has multiple dependencies and all are inside the Solution.
when i am using MSBuild with configuration set to debug the build works fine but when i set the configuration to release it throws the following error
"The type or namespace name 'CommonUtils' does not exist in the namespace 'TS'" now just to clarify the name of the project is  TS.CommonUtils but somehow when building in release this thing is considering TS and CommanUtils different.

Comment: Check the content of your .csproj-file that contains that reference, you'll propably notice that your reference has a condition for the buildconfiguration to be "debug"

Comment: How do you reference TS.CommonUtils assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get a project that  can build flawlessly in debug mode but
>   doesn't in release mode

For your issue,there are already  contributors have given workaround in another case.You can check the below:

```
-- type XXX is only used in release (#if !DEBUG for example) and you are missing a reference to it or a using directive

-- your reference has a condition in your project file enabling it only for debug
```

For details,please refer to this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/331c420c-38b3-40f7-ae65-3473aa12d227/building-in-release-mode-fails-debug-mode-is-ok?forum=msbuild).

Comment: you are correct i can see that in csproj the references are like this
<Reference Include="TS.CommonUtils">
      <HintPath>..\TS.CommonUtils\bin\Debug\TS.CommonUtils.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
how can i make it conditional? so that i can of release the path should be bin/Release/TS.CommonUtils.dll